# Implement Onfailure in webApi controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, razor, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api in which I have this code

```
                   @{
                    AjaxOptions addAjaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        // options will go here
                        OnSuccess = "getData", 
                        OnFailure="selectView('add')",
                        HttpMethod = "Post",
                        Url = "/api/AccountManage/CreateAccount"
                    };
                }
```

In the controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public void CreateAccount(CollaborateurModel item)
        {
        try{}
        catch{
             // return failure
             }
         }
```

I need to implement `failure part` to execute `OnFailure` method .

So how can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using Json Result ([MSDN ref.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx))

Snippet example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateAccount(CollaborateurModel item)()
{
    try{
      //do operations that may fail
      var response = new { Success = true};
      return Json(response );
    }catch{
      var errorResponse= new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "error"};
      return Json(errorResponse);
    }

}
```

Then on the client side you call the controller using JQuery:

```
$(function () {
   $(".test-link").click(function (e) {
      $.post("controllerName/CreateAccount", function (data) {
        if (data.Success == true) {
           alert("Success");
         }
         else {alert(data.ErrorMessage);}
       });
       return false;
    }).fail(function() {
      alert( "error" );
     });
});
```

The fail function on Jquery will handle communication problems that you may have with client-server.

More info about JQuery you can find it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Comment: It is a bad practise to mix regular and APi controller , I think that return type can be `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`

Comment: The Web API controllers return directly objects which are converted to JSON or XML by the formatter. What you're showing is code for an MVC controller. Please, update or delete ypur answer.

Comment: That's true, when I saw controller I thought it was related to MVC. If it was a MVC you can return JsonResult, that's correct. Did you try this solution or something similar? Lamloumi

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your desired response status code, you can use the BadRequest, NotFound or InternalServerError result classes. Each of these have a constructor that has an optional parameter for an error message.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateAccount(CollaborateurModel item)
{
    try
    {
        // Do your thing
    }
    catch
    {
        // Return a HTTP 400 result
        return BadRequest("This is an error message");
    }
}
```